# CakePHP order by DESC not working

Tags: cakephp

I have a following code:

```
if($item_id!=0)
{
  $conditions = array(
    'AND' => array(
      array('OR' => array(array('Message.receiver_id' =>$member_id), 
      array('Message.member_id' =>$member_id))), array('Message.item_id'=>$item_id)));
}
else if($trip_id!=0)
{
  $conditions = array(
    'AND' => array(
      array('OR' => array(array('Message.receiver_id' =>$member_id), 
      array('Message.member_id' =>$member_id))), array('Message.trip_id'=>$trip_id)));
}
$lastMessage=$this->Message->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions),
array('order'=>'Message.id DESC'));
print_r($lastMessage);
```

The code is returning the desired results.
The only issue is that it is **NOT** giving the back in `DESCENDING ORDER of id`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$lastMessage=$this->Message->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions,'order'=>array('Message.id' => 'DESC')));
```

Answer (score 3):

The `conditions` and the `order` keys go in the same array, the correct syntax is

```
find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions'=>$conditions,
        'order'=> 'Message.id DESC'
    )
);
```

or

```
'order' => array('Message.id' => 'desc')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if($item_id!=0)
{
    $conditions = array(
        'AND' => array(
            array('OR' => array(array('Message.receiver_id' =>$member_id),
            array('Message.member_id' =>$member_id))
            ),
            array('Message.item_id'=>$item_id)   
        )
    );
}
else if($trip_id!=0)
{
    $conditions = array(
        'AND' => array(
            array('OR' => array(array('Message.receiver_id' =>$member_id),
            array('Message.member_id' =>$member_id))
            ),
            array('Message.trip_id'=>$trip_id)   
        )
    );
}

$conditions = array('order' => 'Message.id DESC');

$lastMessage=$this->Message->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
print_r($lastMessage);
```

Comment: in this way the 'order' key  is inside the 'conditions' array. I think it would give an error

Comment: $conditions['conditions'] = array('field' => 'your conditions');
$conditions['order'] = array('Field' => 'ASC') work property!

Comment: so you'll have `'conditions' => ['conditions' => [...], 'order' => [...] ]`. I don't think it would work but actually I never tried

Comment: You should try it, this is an extraction of a code that currently is running

Comment: I tried and as expected I got an error. Instead it works if I use `find('all', $conditions));` but it's not what you wrote in your answer

Comment: The question is clear "CakePHP order by DESC not working"

In my answer I supouse $conditions contain other part who is not appear. I prefer to leave this topic. I've been using these conditions long time in a variety of projects and all work correctly.